# Remove the label from a default tick

Tags: plotting, ticks

How can I delete tick labels -2 and 2 so that the values -1.8 and 1.8 doesn't overlap with each other; i.e., I want to keep the ticks at -2 and 2, but not their labels.

This is the code I am using:

```
plot = Plot[{-6 x - x^3/3 + 10 ArcTan[x]}, {x, -2.2, 2.2}]
ticks = Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}] @@ PlotRange[plot][[1]];
ticks2 = Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}] @@ PlotRange[plot][[2]];
newticks = {{0.72, 0.72}, {-0.72, -0.72}}~Join~ticks;
newticks2 = {{1.80, 1.80}, {-1.80, -1.80}}~Join~ticks2;
Show[plot, Ticks -> {newticks, newticks2}]
```

[image: Overlaped plot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modify `newticks2` to remove the unwanted ticks:

```
newticks3 = newticks2 /. {2. | -2., __} :> Sequence[]; (* or *)
newticks3 = DeleteCases[newticks2, {2. | -2., __}]  (* thanks: MikeHoneychurch *)

Show[plot, Ticks -> {newticks, newticks3}]
```

[image]

**Update:** To remove the labels and modify the major ticks to minor ticks at `2` and `-2`:

```
newticks4 = newticks2 /. {x : 2. | -2., __} :> {x, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}};  
Show[plot, Ticks -> {newticks, newticks4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you It works but now  I want to ask you what are the "___" for?

Comment: @Shai, you are welcome. [___ (BlankNullSequence)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlankNullSequence.html) is  _a pattern object that can stand for any sequence of **zero or more** Mathematica expressions_. Btw, I meant to use  [__ (BlankSequence)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlankSequence.html) . Updated with the correction.

Comment: Maybe also add a `DeleteCases` version?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch,  great idea. Thank you.